# Inno Setup: register (unsigned) assemblies

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, assemblies, inno-setup

I need to register some assemblies into my Inno Setup script and found this code:

```
Source: "Files\MyAssembly.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; StrongAssemblyName: "MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=48d60606109a2257, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL"; Flags: "gacinstall sharedfile uninsnosharedfileprompt"
```

the problem is my dll is not signed and I'm not found the option for C++/CLI dll in VS2008 to sign it!

Error message: Install assembly failed; code 0x80131044

How can I register unsigned assemblies or how can I sign C++/CLI dll's in Visual Studio 2008?

Thank you in advance !

greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not signed, you can't install it in the GAC.
If you need it "registered" for COM interop, you need to call RegAsm with the /codebase parameter.

Comment: OK! And how can I sign my C++/CLI dll in Visual Studio 2008? Thank you!

Comment: A very quick [google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=++sign+code+to+install+into+the+gac) would have given you [one answer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815808) and the same article copied onto [other sites](http://www.vkinfotek.com/assemblyhowto.html).